# What will be the best approach local storage

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know which approach will be better for below scenario:

I have 100 products type`(for ex. Dress, pant)` and each has >100 brands, I have one service api which have two end points,

```
end pt1 : if i call this i will get all product types and all corresponding brands.

end pt2: if i call this i will get all brands for a single product type.
```

My approach is,

> call endpt1 and store this information in local storage and if you
>   move from one product page to other you dont have to call api again to
>   get all brands for this product type.

But someone suggested,

> dont store anything call end pt2 if you land on any product page.

which approach should be best in respect to time, accuracy, and code maintenance?

Comment: Retrieval time? Use local storage. Accuracy? Always load it from the API. Maintenance? Should be the same if you can write good code.

Comment: If use localStorage you need a synchronization strategy for data changes

Comment: local storage is subject to possible failure due to user configuration and user manipulation... I'll rather call the api a hundred times than rely on local storage. But that's just the paranoiac me, because if your data is not "sensitive", loading one time is a hundred times better. Combine them, store pt1 and bring as needed pt2.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL the program is running on user's machine, drop any illusion that you can *protect* from manipulation. Also, `localStorage` is strictly strings; if you're looking to store a lot of data, you should probably look into [IndexedDB](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use localstorage unless I absolutely have to. Local caches get stale, so you have to sync them. Local storage can fail if you exceed the storage limit. By necessity, it adds complexity to your code (2 sources of data instead of one).

If you find that calling the API is too slow for each screen, you can optimize for performance at that point. I wouldn't do it beforehand.

Even if you have to optimize, local storage wouldn't be my first choice. I'd cache the data in memory (a global variable) and perform client-side routing or something.